# Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster when node exists

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, magento2.4.6

I am having an issue where, when I try to reindex my site, I receive the following error:

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

The issue is, when I use Curl to check the same url in the config, it returns an active search instance.

Here is what I have so far:

Site is Magento 2.4.6, which uses Elasticsearch 8 according to documentation:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html
The instance I am using is Amazon OpenSearch 2.5, which is supported as of 2.4.6 as well.

Config in env.php:

```
        'catalog' => [
            'search' => [
                'engine' => 'elasticsearch8',
                'elasticsearch8_server_hostname' => 'https://mysearchurl.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com', //Not Actual Url
                'elasticsearch8_server_port' => '443',
                'elasticsearch8_index_prefix' => 'test'
            ]
```

And when I run Curl with the url "https://mysearchurl.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443" I get this (names and uuid values are modified):

```
{
  "name" : "bc4c7e7941061dec5cbe7d638a05041",
  "cluster_name" : "391053442547:site-val",
  "cluster_uuid" : "nOY5BNj8Rnh6s5m1dtClDw",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : "2.5.0",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2023-03-02T04:31:26.269983Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.4.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}-
```

Comment: Cloud you please check this link :- https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-elasticsearch-no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster/

Comment: Check if elastic search is running, no alive nodes indicate elastic search service is not running.